# Как сделать круг с зазубринами(треугольниками) по всей границе круга?

Tags: html, css

[image: 1]

Можно ли сделать такой круг средствами css?

Я имею ввиду такую границу с зазубринами.

Comment: вы не прикрепили изображение

Comment: сейчас картинку видно?

Comment: Можно, clip-path: polygon( ), долго нудно и IE и EDGE не будет работать

Comment: Сделайте canvas и нарисуйте что вам нужно. Или прозрачную PNG, я кажется видел что то подобное в вордарте

Answer (score 4):

это мой самый идиотский ответ))))))))))  Просто хотелось попробовать.
Cкрит только для того, что бы не сидеть и не прописывать каждому элементу трансфомацию. Кому не лень пусть в чистый css  переделает...

```js
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('blocks');
for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].style.transform = 'rotate(' + [i * 10] + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background: transparent;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blocks {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  background: orange;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
    <div class="blocks"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```